# API call in Javascript returns CORS error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm integrating Google Maps API with Forecast.io's DarkSky API. My goal is that the user receives weather information upon clicking a marker on the map. Here is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var darkRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var darkURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/API_KEY/"
    .concat(marker.position.lat().toString(), marker.position.lng().toString());
    darkRequest.open("GET", darkURL, false);
    darkRequest.send();
    console.log(darkRequest.status);
});
```

As you can see, I haven't done the infowindow yet but I'm trying to conquer the CORS error I keep getting, first. This is my first time working with either API and API calls in general. What do I need to do to have this call go through successfully?

Here is the link to the weather API: [DarkSkyAPI](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#forecast_call)

Thanks in advance,

Chase

Comment: read this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

Comment: Have you checked out the [js library they linked](https://github.com/iantearle/forecast.io-javascript-api)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a CORS error, you need to either use JSONP, which is not recommended:

**Options**

The API request may optionally be modified through the use of query parameters. It will respond to the following:

**callback=[callback]:** Return the API response as **JSONP**. **Please use caution when using this, since exposing your API key to the public is a security hazard** and, if abused, will result in the revokation of your API key. However, if developing a personal- or internal-use app, this is a convenient method of doing so.

or (Looks like they expect you to) proxy the request through your server. Which keeps your API key local to your server.

JSONP code which works for me (using JQuery, but that isn't required, API key removed, but **not recommended per their docs**):

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(), 
    draggable: true, 
    map:map, 
    title: map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.setTitle(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue());
    var darkURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/API_KEY/".concat(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
   // Using JSONP
   $.ajax({
     url: darkURL,
   // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
     jsonp: "callback",
   // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
     dataType: "jsonp",
   // Work with the response
     success: function( response ) {
       console.log( response ); // server response
     }
   });
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Comment: I added &callback=blargh to the URL to see if that did anything (blargh being a function that just dumps what is passed) but nothing happened. I'm still getting the error. Due to hosting issues, php proxy is unlikely.

Comment: It works for me if I use [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).  You have to remove the XmlHttpRequest as that will not work if CORS are not allowed.

Comment: Will your map page be available to the general public (even with a login requirement), or is it for internal use, say on a corporate LAN where all your users are trusted? If the page is used only by your trusted colleagues, then sure, you can use JSONP. If it's open to the public at all, then you really must proxy the requests through a server (using any server language you want), otherwise someone can misuse your API key.

Comment: Only one other person was ever going to see it but I've already got the proxy working despite the hosting issues I was having earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub from Bergi's link has a proxy set up already so all I had to do was apply that and the API call started to work.